# How to let the Coin-or Cbc Solver write solution file?

Tags: coin-or-cbc, coin-or, coin-or-clp

I use the C++ library of COIN-OR Cbc Solver to solve some LP problems. And I can't find anywhere a function or something that writes the solution file. I think somewhere in the code there is this functionality because you can use COIN-OR's command line interface to write the solution as a file ( `cbc problem.lp solve -solu solution.txt` ). I found a few functions in the `ClpModel` class that set parameters, namely `setIntParam` , `setDblParam` and `setStrParam`. But they couldn't help me either. Thanks in advance.